# Calculus Michael Spivak Conic Section Step Explanation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: Two cones of slope C]

> For any given two coordinates $x$ and $y$, the point $(x,y,0)$ in the horizontal plane has distance $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ from the origin, and thus
>   $$\text{(1)}\; \; \; \; \; \; (x,y,z)\; \text{is in the cone if and only if}\; z=\pm C\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

How is $\text{(1)}$ justified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, the slope $C$ is the change in height divided by the horizontal distance change. In this case, going from the origin $(0,0,0)$ to any non-zero point $(x,y,z)$ on the conic section, the change in height is $\pm z$ (depending on whether the point is above or below the horizontal plane, so $z$ is either positive or negative) and the change horizontal distance is $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. Thus, you get

$$C = \frac{\pm z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \implies z = \pm C\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

For the origin itself, you have $x = y = z = 0$, so \eqref{eq1A} still holds in that case as well.